# Protobufs build but are not being linked to main program using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am trying to build and execute a program that uses protobufs. I am building this project with CMake3. The problem is when I make the project i get this error

```
fatal error: 
      'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found
#include <google/protobuf/stubs/common.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I will post my directory structure for this project

[directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7cT4.png)

[directory structure expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33pxW.png)

Here are my CMakeLists.txt files

top level under TestCode/

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_subdirectory(protobufs)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

CMakeList.txt under main/

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(test_exe 
    main.cc 
)
target_link_libraries(protos ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

CMakeLists under protobufs/

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS 
    dog.proto
)
add_library(protos ${PROTO_SRCS})

target_link_libraries(protos 
    PUBLIC
    ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES}
)

target_include_directories(protos
    PUBLIC
    ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

This is how I building the project

```
cd build
cmake ..
make -j8
```

I can not figure out why the protobufs are not being found for the main program. if I just try to build the protobufs using make they build successfully. Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT: I SOLVED IT.
In my CMakeLists.txt in main/ I needed to add test_exe in my target_link_libraries

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


add_executable(test_exe 
    main.cc 
)
target_link_libraries(test_exe protos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

> 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h' file not found

is because you are not telling the compiler where your protobuf header files are.  Can you search your computer for 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.h'?  If it is not installed, you need to install it (using your system package manager).  If it is installed, you need to add an include directory rule for the parent directory (the one containing 'google') in CMake.

Comment: I have that file in that directory. Can you explain what you mean by add the include path in CMake. I tried but might be doing it wrong